# What is the correct syntax for finding the " symbol using the FIND worksheet function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In other words given that the "find_value" needs to be surrounded by quotation marks e.g."wanted text" How do I escape the " symbol?

" is not valid
""" is not valid, and
"/"" is not valid either

Comment: First option mentioned by you works in Excel 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"` as an escape character, e.g.

- to look for a single `"` use it four times in the function (`"""""`):

  - first one is opening quote of the string
  - second one is the escape character
  - third one is the actual quote you're looking for
  - fourth one is closing the string
- `"wanted text"`: start and end your term with three quotes (`"""`), same logic:

  - first quote starts the string
  - second one is the escape character
  - third one is the actual quote to find

[image]